# Android complete app uninstaller

Tags: android, file-management, uninstall

There are over 100 different *uninstall* utilities for Android.  I am searching for one with specific functionality:

- In addition to performing all the functionality of Android's standard app uninstaller (which deletes the APK, the cache, and most data), also deletes all other data created by the app.
- Does not keep a service resident when not in use.
- Either automatically runs when using Android's standard app uninstaller or can be used **in place** of the standard uninstaller as a way to completely uninstall apps.  (**Not** looking for a general "cleaning tool" that is always running.)
- Does not make internet connections.
- Works on Android KitKat.

*Why?*

I've noticed that a significant number of apps leave "danglers"... items created by the app that are not removed when uninstalling the app.

Comment: You may be asking for something difficult to achieve. A lot of applications have filesystem permissions granted. This allows them to write as many "danglers" as they want. Whatever application you choose will need to keep track of these writes, and roll them back at uninstall time.

Comment: @baitisj You are correct.  On the other hand, I remember working with at least one app that could identify and delete "danglers".  I do not know how it worked.  It's possible it had a hard-coded list of common apps.  It's also possible it searched for all folders whose names contained the app name.

Answer (score 1):

You might wish to take a look at **[SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm)**, though you will probably need the [paid version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm.unlocker):

- **also deletes all other data created by the app:** that's what it's famous for, its "Corpse finder" – finding those "left-overs" (or "danglers") after an app has been uninstalled
- **Does not keep a service resident when not in use:** I'm not aware of any (but must admit I've not used the app recently)
- **automatically runs when using Android's standard app uninstaller or can be used in place of the standard uninstaller:** When I've used the app last, it didn't have an "app uninstaller" included. But some time has passed since, and an "AppControl" module has been added meanwhile which, according to the app's description, meets this requirement.
- **Does not make internet connections:** free version has network permissions, most likely for ads. I've never bought the pro version, so I cannot tell about this; it certainly wants to check its license (`vending.CHECK_LICENSE` permission for "Google Play license check"), but I'd expect the paid version to do no other "internet stuff".
- **Works on Android KitKat:** Certainly. App description says "2.3.3 and up", and the [help page](http://sdmaid.darken.eu/help/) has a section specific to "Android 4.4 - SDCard access"

The app doesn't strictly require root, but unleashes its full power when root is available. Listing some features from its app description:

> - Explorer is a full fledged filemanager, use it to crawl through your Androids files.
> - You can use the Searcher if you know what file you are looking for.
> - **The CorpseFinder searches your device for orphaned items and compares those to the list of installed applications.**
> - **AppControl lets you freeze, reset and remove applications (even system apps).**
> - The SystemCleaner scans your device and filters directories which contain unnecessary files. You an even create your own filters!
> - You can optimize and shrink bloated databases to speed up access and free space.
> - View your biggest files and find out what is hogging all the space.
> - Find files that have been modified in the last X minutes.

<sup>(emphasis mine, where something matched your requirements)</sup>

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm.unlocker); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Izzy.  I've used SD Maid quite a bit.  Unfortunately, it routinely makes internet connections, even when all the related settings are disabled.  Regardless, do you know how its corpse finder works?

Comment: Just follow the link to the [help page](http://sdmaid.darken.eu/help/), it's described there. // Sad to read about the internet part. Are you talking about the freemium or the paid version with that? As I've pointed out, the "free" version most likely does that for "revenue" (ads etc.). But again, it's quite a while ago I've last used the app. If your device is rooted, you could try a firewall to keep SDMaid from "calling home" ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link... help that is actually helpful!  :-)  My understanding is that the internet connections are for both the free and the paid versions, but it is a little ambiguous.  The internet calls can definitely be blocked with a firewall, but I'm not a proponent of apps that create active processes (especially active internet processes) when then are not open.

Comment: "help that is actually helpful" – expect the unexpected :) A rare thing, yeah. And correct: apps shouldn't be active when they shouldn't be active (uh). On-Demand apps shouldn't start themselves without being explicitly told by the user. Sorry, wasn't aware of that part here. // Afraid baitisj is right, you won't find a 100% match :( Be welcome to check my lists for [uninstallers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_organize#group_4) and [system cleaners](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_systemcleaner) nevertheless …